# MobileFirst 7.1 cannot export ipa after fixpack 7.1.0.00.20190704-0841

Tags: ibm-mobilefirst

After installing this fixpack xcode will no longer create an IPA.
It was creating an generic xcode archive.
From what i can tell the update cordova lib has 3 private headers:
CDVDebug.h
CDVJSON_private.h
CDVPlugin+Private.h

These private headers end up being included in the products directory during archive.  This is not allowed to create an IPA.  The only way i have been able to create an IPA is by moving those library from private headers to project or public.

Is this a bug in the fix? or is there something else that could be causing the problem.

Comment: What XCode version are you using?

Comment: When you upgraded iFix, did you also upgraded xcode? What was the previous iFix version and the xcode version on which you were able to export to ipa.

Comment: We did not update xcode, just added the fix to the code(Xcode 10.1 Build version 10B61).  Before this fix we were on 7.1.0.0-MFPF-StudioP2-IF201810081403

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found the issue is introduced when we bundled cordova version to 4.0. As you detected correctly its due to "cordova lib having 3 private headers: CDVDebug.h CDVJSON_private.h CDVPlugin+Private.h", once they moved to public, the issue get resolved and ipa can be built. We will be fixing this issue in upcoming v7.1 iFix.